# How to modify $uri to part of uri from request_uri in nginx?

Tags: nginx

Suppose the value of $request_uri is /a/b/c .
The current value of $uri is /index.php .
Is this possible to change my $uri to /b/c .

I have tried this, which doesn't seem to be working,

```
if ($request_uri ~* /a/(.*)/(.*)){
  set $uri /$1/$2;
}
```

But this gives error of *duplicate "uri" variable*.
I also tried,

```
if ($request_uri ~* /a/(.*)/(.*)){
  rewrite ^ /$1/$2 break;
}
```

But $variables don't seem to store values.

Is there a way out? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/718610/how-to-modify-uri-to-part-of-uri-from-request-uri-in-nginx).

It basically needed two rewrites.

```
rewrite ^ $request_uri;
rewrite /.*/(.*)/(.*) /$1/$2;
```

The first rewrite modifies uri from `/index.php -> /a/b/c`.

The second rewrite modifies uri from `/a/b/c -> /b/c`.